# Did anything change in QT_UI_WRAP

Tags: qt, cmake

I am trying to wrap QT UI in QT5 using a command

```
QT5_UI_WRAP (ui_forms/file.h ui_file.ui)
```

I have include QT5Widgets. Somehow this isn't working. Now everywhere I read, this is what needs to be done but there is always an error saying the .h file was not found. I have included the ui_forms folder in include path. Is there anything more that needs to be done with this. ? Am I missing something ?

```
fatal error: ui_results_view.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/src/results_scene.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/location_recognition.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You forgot to post the complete error message.

Comment: The error is just that the header file was not found in one of the includes.

Comment: The error message does not match the example code. Please provide both in their raw form and show the command which resulted in the error as well (``make VERBOSE=1`` to get it).